# How to get metadata (Genre, Artist) from mp3 file?

Tags: python, metadata, mp3, id3, eyed3

I have a problem that confused me. I want to get metadata (especially genre, artist) in python and I've tried some way to do this but each of them return `null`.

I want to get at least one feature (genre, artist) and connect it Spotify or Last.fm api to get information about the raw mp3 file and choose the other file in library for mixing.

Here some code that I tried:

```
from tinytag import TinyTag

file2 = "/home/orhanors/Desktop/music/yokohama.mp3"
a_tag = TinyTag.get(file2)
print(a_tag)
```

Result:

`{"album": null, "albumartist": null, "artist": null, "audio_offset": 138, "bitrate": 192, "channels": 2, "comment": null, "composer": null, "disc": null, "disc_total": null, "duration": 417.604742145821, "filesize": 10017364, "genre": null, "samplerate": 44100, "title": null, "track": null, "track_total": null, "year": null}`

```
import eyed3

audio = eyed3.load(file2)
print(audio.tag.artist)
print(audio.tag.album)
print(audio.tag.title)
```

Result:

```
None
None
None
```

Comment: Could it be that the data is simply not encoded in your MP3 file? I mean - the functions works well, and returns some data that looks realistic. Perhaps the encoder did not attach tags.

Comment: I agree with @AmitaiIrron, it could simply be due to the fact that those items are included in the file's metadata. Suggest you use some third-party to verify the information is present in any test file you use for testing your own code.

Comment: I tried to download mp3 from other platforms and it worked. Thanks a lot